# How to use cogs from Folders in a Folder

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm currently working on a Discord bot and am trying to get the cogs from more than one folder (better order) but I can't get it to work, please help me lol

At the moment I use this system and it works:

```
for cogpath in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if cogpath.endswith(".py"):
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{cogpath[:-3]}')
```

I tried to expand it with a second field:

```
for cogpath in os.listdir("cogs/Folder1"):
        if cogpath.endswith(".py"):
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{cogpath[:-3]}')
```

But all I get is this:
`Error: Extension 'cogs.MyCog' could not be loaded.`

Would be awesome if you could help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `load_extension` at the new path

```
for cogpath in os.listdir("cogs/Folder1"):
    if cogpath.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.Folder1.{cogpath[:-3]}')
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much, tried it again and now it works, great work, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i tried that Cog.folder but it only specifies one folder. the snippet im providing it will load the cog and the subfolders too.

```
async def load():
for root, _, files in os.walk('./cogs'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)[len("./cogs/"):][:-3].replace(os.path.sep, '.')
            await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{path}')
```